# FFmpeg possible bug with -pre flag

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, decoding, transcoding

I was studying the ffpresets and avpresets but I stumbled upon something interesting.

According to the [ffmpeg docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#avpreset-files):

> First ffmpeg searches for a file named codec_name-arg.avpreset in the above-mentioned directories, where codec_name is the name of the codec to which the preset file options will be applied. For example, if you select the video codec with -vcodec libvpx and use -pre 1080p, then it will search for the file libvpx-1080p.avpreset.

> If no such file is found, then ffmpeg will search for a file named arg.avpreset in the same directories.

I have a preset stored in the correct directory:

```
$ ls ~/.avconv/
libvpx-1080p.avpreset
```

Therefore, the following command should work:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libvpx -pre 1080p output.mp4
```

But instead it results in the follwing error:

```
Preset 1080p specified for stream 0:1, but could not be opened.
```

However, the following command works:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libvpx -pre libvpx-1080p output.mp4
```

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding the docs?

EDIT: I originally tried with the latest ffmpeg version available from the repositories (4.3.1). However, I then decided to confirm this is still the case with the latest version built from [source](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg), which yields:

```
~/Downloads/FFmpeg$ ./ffmpeg --version
ffmpeg version N-102649-g3ac7d99428 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10 (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1)
configuration: --disable-x86asm --enable-libvpx
libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
libavcodec     59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
libavformat    59.  2.101 / 59.  2.101
libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
libavfilter     8.  0.101 /  8.  0.101
libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
```

EDIT 2: Adding the whole log of the failing command as requested

```
$ ./ffmpeg -i ../input.mp4 -vcodec libvpx -pre 1080p ../output.mp4
ffmpeg version N-102649-g3ac7d99428 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1)
  configuration: --disable-x86asm --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavcodec     59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
  libavformat    59.  2.101 / 59.  2.101
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  0.101 /  8.  0.101
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '../input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2015-08-07T09:13:36.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:30.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4675 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4486 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-08-07T09:13:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-08-07T09:13:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Preset 1080p specified for stream 0:1, but could not be opened.
```

Comment: Share full log of failing command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-pre` option accepts stream specifiers and in the absence of any, will be applied to all streams. Since the default audio encoder for MP4 is `aac`, ffmpeg will look for `aac-1080p.avpreset` and then `1080p.avpreset` Since neither of those exist, ffmpeg errors out.

Change `-pre` to either `-vpre` or `-pre:v`.

Comment: Interesting. And how can I make it work as in the example in the docs? My end goal is to have a bunch of different vpre, apre, spre etc codec presets and a bunch of quality presets (1080p, 2160p etc). So I can just do ```ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vpre h264 -pre 1080p -apre aac -pre 1536kb output.mp4``` or something similar.

Comment: You can have one preset per-stream. So, use a stream-specifier.